# Dagger 2. Как правильно добавлять зависимости

Tags: android, mvp, dagger2

Только начал изучать Dagger 2 и есть некоторые вопросы на которые пока не могу найти ответ. 
1. Заботится ли даггер об уничтожении ссылок. Т.е у меня есть вот такой код

```
private MODEL view;
    @Inject
    protected Model mModel;
    @Inject
    protected CompositeDisposable mCompositeDisposable;

    @Override
    public void attachView(MODEL view) {
        this.view = view;
        BasePresenterComponent component = DaggerBasePresenterComponent.builder()
                .basePresenterModule(new BasePresenterModule())
                .build();
        mModel = component.getModel();
        mCompositeDisposable = component.getCompositeDisposable();
    }
```

до использования даггера я в методе detachView уничтожал некоторые ссылки

```
@Override
    public void detachView() {
        view = null;
        mModel = null;
        if (mCompositeDisposable != null && !mCompositeDisposable.isDisposed()) {
            mCompositeDisposable.dispose();
        }
    }
```

Нужно ли это делать при использовании даггера если правильно указать Scope?

2. Вот так же пример кода

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IOnFragmentInteractionListener {

   ```
   RequestFragment mRequestFragment;
   OrderFragment mOrderFragment;
   FragmentTransaction mTransaction;

   //some code

   private void startFragment(Fragment fragment) {
       **mTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();**
       mTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
       mTransaction.commit();
   }
   ```

   }

так вот нужно ли такие зависимости как FragmentTransaction выносить в модули даггера или все же оставить их в активити? 
Я написал вот такой метод, но не уверен в его правильности:

```
@Module
public class MainActivityModule {

    //some code

    @Provides
    public FragmentTransaction transaction(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        return activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    }
}
```

Ну и если кто-то накинет пару статей по архитектуре Dagger в MVP, особенно хотелось бы видеть какой-то код на GitHub буду рад до безумия=) Всем добра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Заботится ли даггер об уничтожении ссылок.

Нет, не заботится. Аннотация `@Inject` привязывает к ссылке объект, который вы создаете в `Module` с помощью `provide` и всё. Аннотация Scope сама по себе создает только синглтон. Даггер сам ничего не уничтожает и никакой магии нет. Все скоупы надо уничтожать самому.

Кстати, лучше не инжектить `compositeDisposable`, потому что может возникнуть ситуация, когда в каком-то презентере у вас идет запрос в сеть, а в другом презентере вы делаете `dispose` и запрос отменится, эти действия по сути не должны быть связаны, но так как у вас `compositeDisposable` один объект на все презентеры, то такое может возникнуть. Лучше создать BasePresenter и положить туда, а потом от него наследоваться, тогда для каждого презентера будет отдельный объект `compositeDisposable`

> Нужно ли такие зависимости как FragmentTransaction выносить в модули
>   даггера или все же оставить их в активити?

Все зависимости, которые имеют нестабильный жизненный цикл через даггер лучше не инжектить( Activity, Fragment, SupportFragmentManager и т.д.), потому что тогда, надо будет следить, чтобы не было утечек памяти, чистить скоупы, а каких-то существенных плюсов такой подход не даёт, только усложняет тестирование.

Начать изучать даггер можно по циклу [этих](https://habr.com/en/post/279125/) статей. Хорошее и простое объяснение, главное прочитать все статьи, потому что в последних статьях автор меняет свое мнение о некоторых вещах, которые он описывал в первых статьях.

P.S. Если вам нужен хороший Router в проекте и возможность делать навигацию в презентерах, посмотрите в сторону [Cicerone](https://github.com/terrakok/Cicerone)

Comment: Цикл статей о dagger это хорошо, но прошло уже 3 года с момента публикации. Я бы порекомендовал еще эту https://m.habr.com/ru/post/434618/  статью.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.